# Como inserir legenda em mapas do ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapas

Como faço para inserir a legenda e para mudar a escala do mapa para graus?

```
library("rgeos")
library("maptools")
library("ggplot2")
library("mapproj")

cores1 = c('brown2', 'aquamarine2', 'darkgray','darkolivegreen1', 'floralwhite')

ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=mapa, mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
                        color="black", fill=cores1[mapa$tb]) + 
           coord_map() + 
           labs(y="latitude", x="longitude") +
           theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust = 5))
```

[image: map]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `ggplot` não está incluindo a legenda porque você está atribuindo cores como atributo e não como `mapping`. |Definir atributos não inclui novas informações no gráfico (mapa), apenas muda aspectos visuais. Por este motivo não precisam de legenda.

Já mapear uma variável em algum aspecto estético (dentro do `aes(...)` é adicionar informações ao gráfico (mapa), para esta informação poder ser decodificada, ela necessita de legenda.

Ao simplesmente incluir o `fill = tb` dentro do `aes(...)`, o próprio ggplot já cria a legenda.

#### Recriando os dados

utilizei este objeto `mapa` para construir como mapas abaixo:

```
mapa <- map_data("state")
mapa$tb <- factor(sample(1:5, size = nrow(mapa), replace = TRUE))
```

#### Plotando os mapas

Ao simplesmente remover o `fill=cores1[mapa$tb]` e incluir `fill = tb` dentro do `aes()`

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=mapa, mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill = tb),
               color="black") + 
  coord_map() + 
  labs(y="latitude", x="longitude") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust = 5))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas nesta solução perdemos as cores que você desejava. Para reinclui-las com a metodologia proposta, temos que adicionar uma escala manual de cores com a função `scale_fill_manual()`. O argumento que será passado para esta função é justamente o vetor com as cores que você escolheu. O argumento `values`deve ser explícito. Assim temos:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=mapa, mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill = tb),
               color="black") + 
  coord_map() + 
  labs(y="latitude", x="longitude") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust = 5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cores1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já havia resolvido, mas de toda forma agradeço a explicação.